# A simple plotting but where's the mistake?

Tags: pgfplots

What's wrong with that following ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
grid=major,
xmin=8,
xmax=22,
ymin=40,
ymax=80,
xlabel={heure},
ylabel={Concentration d'ozone en $\mu g/m^3$},
xtick={8,9,...,21},
ytick={40,50,...,70},
tick style={very thick},
legend style={at={(rel axis cs:0.5,1)},anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}]
\addplot[blue,thick,samples=100]{-0.7*x^2+21*x-86};
\addlegendentry{$y=-0,7x^2+21x-86$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What's your question? How do you expect it to look? And please always make your code compilable (MWE).

Comment: Common mistake: the default `domain` is `-5:5`, add e.g. `domain=8:22` in  the `axis` (or `\addplot`) settings.